# How can I say when referring to occurrences of an operator?

Tags: programming

I'm documenting a coding guide.

Please help me out regarding how to indicate occurrences of an operator in an expression.

For example:

```
X = A + B + C + 3
```

In this situation, can you tell me a proper word that must come in the placeholder below?

*This expression includes three ________ of the addition operator.*

Or, is there any other way to say it differently?

Comment: Why do you think that _occurrences_ doesn't fit?

Comment: I just was not sure if *occurrences* might be a good option and is used typically in this case.

Comment: I'd go with *instances*, but I'm not a coder.

Comment: @PhilSweet -- I'd go with instances too, but then I suppose I'm no longer a coder.

Comment: I slightly prefer "occurrences" over "instances", but I'd probably just say "This expression contains three plus signs."

Comment: Thank you. Then, may I ask an extra question in a more complicated context like: A > B >= C < D, can I say in the following ways?

Comment: 1) The expression has a multiple number of consecutive comparison **symbols**.

Comment: 2) The expression has consecutive **occurrences** of comparison **operators**.

Comment: Don't say "has a multiple number of [something]", say "has multiple [something]". (And note that in the programming languages I'm familiar with it doesn't make sense to say *A > B >= C < D* because the *A > B* part would be evaluated first and return a Boolean.)